# iOS - Archiving error: no unexpired provisioning profiles that contain any of the keychains signing certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I created a new AppId and a new provisioning files for development and distribution. Then I downloaded the 2 new provisioning files into my xCode.

I also have a working set of keychain access files which work with my other apps.

But when I try to archive my new codebase, I get the error:

```
no unexpired provisioning profiles that contain any of the keychains signing certificates
```

Would anyone know how I can configure the rest of this application?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Was my answer helpful Alex?

Comment: @CodeMonkey thank you for following up. I did the refresh that you mentioned. It seemed to have pulled the latest data, but when I tried to archive, it gave the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the provisioning profiles from your keychain. Remove those the remove the ones in xcode and also check the provisioning profiles on apple developer site as well. You have remove all of the invalid ones then try to refresh and get the whole thing done. If problems persist, then revoke the provisioning profiles that you have and create another certificate and request a new set of profiles. This is what I was told by apple Dev support when I got into this problem. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the App ID you set for your project matches exactly the one in your new provisioning profile. Also, from Xcode, select the app target, go to Build Settings, Code Signing and check that your new provisioning profile is selected in the drop down box.

Comment: Martin I think you are onto something with the code signing suggestion. I have nothing selected there.  But also when I try to select something, all the options are grayed out. Do you know why this would be the case? Thanks!

Comment: @Genadinik Select the app target, go to the Info tab and check that the Bundle identifier is compatible with the App ID of your provisioning profile. Respect uppercase and lowercase letters.

Comment: Martin yes I double and triple checked those, and they are identical.

Comment: @Genadinik Is the developer certificate associated with the provisioning profile? You can check that from the iOS Provisioning Portal. Check also in your Keychain that your certificate (with private key) is installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This exact thing happened to me when I upgraded my xcode. I don't know if it works for you or not but what I did was temporarily removed the provisioning profiles from xcode and then I used the option refresh. Xcode downloaded the working and valid profiles for me. Only then I was able to select the right profile in target and project level and was able to archive. So try removing the profiles from xcode and refresh and see if this works out for you.

Comment: from the top right side of xcode select organizer. then go to provisioning profiles. remove the one that is not valid. then on the left collomn you should see the name of your profile I.E. your own name or the team name. press on that if there is any invalid frofile in that window select and remove it. then on the bottom right side you see the refresh option. press on that, enter your apple id if nessesary and xcode will do the rest.

Comment: Oh I forgot to tell you that you need to remove the invalid profiles from keychain also then use the refresh. Sorry :(

Comment: I did the refresh, but I still get the same error.  I have been messing with it, but not sure what might be the problem.